# How can I open a file through terminal of goormIde

Tags: ide

I am trying to open file through goormIde terminal but it seems they don't have any command.

I tried using `open`, `xdg-open` and by simply typing the file name but none of it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can open a file with a terminal command `goorm`

```
goorm [file name]
```

See [How do I open a file from goorm terminal?](https://help.goorm.io/en/goormide/18.faq/using-goormide/how-to-open-a-file-from-terminal)

Comment: as in : goorm app.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command - goorm filename

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a link to the command that you have mentioned? Also, use this as a guide while answering questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

In goormide, you can not open a file with the terminal `open` command. It is not supported.

But you can open a file using the search box.
Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open a file in Goorm editor.

You can open a file with a terminal command goorm.
The usage is as following:

```
 goorm [file name]
```

For example, if you want to open

```
 file.json
```

enter the command like this:

```
goorm file.json
```